# BigQuery - how to think about query optimisation when coming from a SQL Server background

Tags: sql, optimization, google-bigquery

I have a background that includes SQL Server and Informix database query optimisation (non big-data). I'm confident in how to maximise database performance on those systems. I've recently been working with BigQuery and big data (about 9+ months), and optimisation doesn't seem to work the same way. I've done some research and read some articles on optimisation, but I still need to better understand the basics of how to optimise on BigQuery.

In SQL Server/Informix, a lot of the time I would introduce a column index to speed up reads. BigQuery doesn't have indexes, so I've mainly been using clustering. When I've done benchmarking after introducing a cluster for a column that I thought should make a difference, I didn't see any significant change. I'm also not seeing a difference when I switch on query cacheing. This could be an unfortunate coincidence with the queries I've tried, or a mistaken perception, however with SQL Server/SQL Lite/Informix I'm used to seeing immediate significant improvement, consistently. Am I misunderstanding clustering (I know it's not exactly like an index, but I'm expecting it should work in a similar type of way), or could it just be that I've somehow been 'unlucky' with the optimisations.

And this is where the real point is. There's almost no such thing as being 'unlucky' with optimisation, but in a traditional RDBMS I would look at the execution plan and know exactly what I need to do to optimise, and find out exactly what's going on. With BigQuery, I can get the 'execution details', but it really isn't telling me much (at least that I can understand) about how to optimise, or how the query really breaks down.

Do I need a significantly different way of thinking about BigQuery? Or does it work in similar ways to an RDBMS, where I can consciously make the first JOINS eliminate as many records as possible, use 'where' clauses that focus on indexed columns, etc. etc.

I feel I haven't got the control to optimise like in a RDBMS, but I'm sure I'm missing a major point (or a few points!). What are the major strategies I should be looking at for BigQuery optimisation, and how can I understand exactly what's going on with queries? If anyone has any links to good documentation that would be fantastic - I'm yet to read something that makes me think "Aha, now I get it!".

Comment: fyr https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-overview

Comment: plus this https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation#using_execution_information This is very much unlike other RDBMS or even other Analytics Data warehouses where you can actually act on what you see in the explain plan. BigQuery only gives you an idea on where the possible bottleneck but most are not actionable

Comment: I suggest try posting some of your queries to Stackover and the story what you tried to update. BQ tag is being monitored by google engineers as well, and if they spot something obvious it will suggest a nice alternative. Clustering if used correctly should produce you smaller bills and a bit faster queries.

Comment: [Introduction to BigQuery best practices](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is absolutely a paradigm shift in how you think. You're right: you don't have hardly any control in execution. And you'll eventually come to appreciate that. You do have control over architecture, and that's where a lot of your wins will be. (As others mentioned in comments, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-overview) is definitely helpful too.)

I've personally found that premature optimization is one of the biggest issues in BigQuery—often the things you do trying to make a query faster actually have a negative impact, because things like table scans are well optimized and there are internals that you can impact (like restructuring a query in a way that seems more optimal, but forces additional shuffles to disk for parallelization).

Some of the biggest areas our team HAS seem greatly improve performance are as follows:

1. Use semi-normalized ([nested/repeated](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated)) schema when possible. By using nested `STRUCT`/`ARRAY` types in your schema, you ensure that the data is colocated with the parent record. You can basically think of these as tables within tables. The use of `CROSS JOIN UNNEST()` takes a little getting used to, but eliminating those joins makes a big difference (especially on large results).
2. Use [partitioning/clustering](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables) on large datasets when possible. I know you mention this, just make sure that you're pruning what you can using `_PARTITIONTIME` when possible, and also using clutering keys that make sense for your data. Keep in mind that clustering basically sorts the storage order of the data, meaning that the optimizer knows it doesn't have to continue scanning if the criteria has been satisfied (so it doesn't help as much on low-cardinality values)
3. Use [analytic window functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts) when possible. They're very well optimized, and you'll find that BigQuery's implementation is very mature. Often you can eliminate grouping this way, or filter our more of your data earlier in the process. Keep in mind that sometimes filtering data in derived tables or Common Table Expressions (CTEs/named [`WITH`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with-clause) queries) *earlier* in the process can make a more deeply nested query perform better than trying to do everything in one flat layer.
4. Keep in mind that results for Views and Common Table Expressions (CTEs/named `WITH` queries) aren't materialized during execution. If you use the CTE multiple times, it will be executed multiple times. If you join the same View multiple times, it will be executed multiple times. This was hard for members of our team who came from the world of materialized views (although it looks like somethings in the works for that in BQ world since there's an unused `materializedView` property showing in the API).
5. Know how the query cache works. Unlike some platforms, the cache **only** stores the output of the outermost query, not its component parts. Because of this, only an identical query against unmodified tables/views will use the cache—and it will typically only persist for 24 hours. Note that if you use non-deterministic functions like `NOW()` and a host of other things, the results are non-cacheable. See details under the [Limitations and Exceptions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results) sections of the docs.
6. Materialize your own copies of expensive tables. We do this a lot, and use [scheduled queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries) and scripts ([API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/) and [CLI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool)) to normalize and save a native table copy of our data. This allows very efficient processing and fast responses from our client dashboards as well as our own reporting queries. It's a pain, but it works well.

Hopefully that will give you some ideas, but also feel free to post queries on SO in the future that you're having a hard time optimizing. Folks around here are pretty helpful when you let them know what your data looks like and what you've already tried.

Good luck!